# Display a specific template when Django raises an exception

Tags: python, django, exception, django-templates

In my django app, I have multiple places where I raise a specific custom exception `DeserializationError`. My goal is to show/redirect to a pretty page to show the user this error, including the error message, when this error is raised. Basically, a page that says something like

> Something went wrong. Please contact webmaster@email.com.
>   Error: DeserializationError. Message: SomeModel, "somemodel", does not exist.

Would this even be possible? I've been trying to search for a solution but haven't been able to find anything yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely such errors will return HTTP 500 server error.

In django you can write your own custom view to handle such cases and return your own page with the html that you like.

[The 500 (server error) view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/views/#the-500-server-error-view) explains writing server error views. There are more types of errors handled as explained on same page.

Comment: How could I pass in the Error to my custom 500.html page?

Comment: You shouldn't, as it says right in the link @Rohan provided; you'll be receiving the stack trace via email anyway - keep in mind that all of this happens only when `DEBUG = False`

Answer (score 0):

An option for handling HTTP 500 errors, add this to your Settings file,

```
handler500 = 'mysite.views.my_custom_error_view'
```

and in the view, you can render the "error page" using

```
HttpResponseNotFound('<h1>Page not found</h1>')
```

the [server_error()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/views/#django.views.defaults.server_error) view will be overridden by handler500.